# Implicit ViewModel generation from LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, viewmodel

In my project I have a **GenericImageViewModel** which is used by many entities.

Example of getting the ASP User Entity:

```
var query = UserRepository.Get(Id).Select(a => new TRDIdenityViewModel
            {
                FirstName = a.UserProfile.FirstName,
                LastName = a.UserProfile.LastName,
                NickName = a.UserProfile.NickName,
                ProfileImage = a.UserProfile.ProfileImage
            });
```

The ProfileImage is the GenericImageViewModel and has an implicit operator as follows:

```
 public static implicit operator TRDGenericImageViewModel(TRDImage image)
    {
        return new TRDGenericImageViewModel
        {
            Id = image.Id,
            AspectRatio = image.Ratio,
            Url = image.Url,
        };
    }
```

If I run the query Entity Framework throws an exception:

**"Unable to cast the type 'TRDImage' to type 'TRDGenericImageViewModel'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."**

If I create the GenericImageViewModel manually for each ViewModel everything is running fine:

```
var query = UserRepository.Get(Id).Select(a => new TRDIdenityViewModel
            {
                FirstName = a.UserProfile.FirstName,
                LastName = a.UserProfile.LastName,
                NickName = a.UserProfile.NickName,
                ProfileImage = new TRDGenericImageViewModel {
                    Id = a.UserProfile.ProfileImage.Id,
                    AspectRatio = a.UserProfile.ProfileImage.Ratio,
                    Url = a.UserProfile.ProfileImage.Url,
                },
            });
```

But in this case I have to copy and paste the TRDGenericImageViewModel generation in every ViewModel and thats not the way it should goes. If something changed I have to modify all related classes.

So is there a way to avoid this exception?

Comment: You can work-around this by using `.AsEnumerable()` prior to the lambda that creates your custom ViewModel class instance.

Comment: Using `.AsEnumerable()` prior the lambda fetches the entities from the database. So it is not possible to `Count()` over related entities not included in the base query.

Comment: Your posting does not demonstrate any invokation of `Count`

Comment: My fault. Updated Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.AsEnumerable()` prior lambda is not possible due to selects later in that query.

```
var query = UserRepository
            .Get(Id)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(a => new TRDIdenityViewModel
            {
                FirstName = a.UserProfile.FirstName,
                LastName = a.UserProfile.LastName,
                NickName = a.UserProfile.NickName,
                ProfileImage = new TRDGenericImageViewModel
                {
                    Id = a.UserProfile.ProfileImage.Id,
                    AspectRatio = a.UserProfile.ProfileImage.Ratio,
                    Url = a.UserProfile.ProfileImage.Url,
                },
                Statistics = new TRDUserStatisticsViewModel
                {
                    PostCount = a.Posts.Count(),
                    CommentCount = a.Comments.Count(),
                    ImageCount = a.Images.Count(),
                    VideoCount = a.Videos.Count(),
                    VoteCount = a.PostVotes.Count(),
                }
            });
```

When calling `.AsEnumerable()` only the entities included by the Include statement are counted. But if the user has more than 1000 Posts and 10.000 Votes the query is a data nightmare.

Comment: I suggest ditching the repository-pattern and using your EF Entities object directly.